# Is there a copy-mode ( like in tmux ) for ITerm2?

Tags: tmux, iterm2, iterm

I like the `copy-mode` in tmux because it lets me search,copy text in the terminal without reaching for the mouse. The `vi-bindings` in copy mode is an added bonus. Is there anything similar for `iterm2` ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [Copy-Mode (Cmd-Shift-c)](https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-copymode.html).

(or [Cached copy since they're down right now](https://web.archive.org/web/20170926173126/https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-copymode.html))